# Orientation change and screen.width

Tags: css, viewport

I noticed that changing device orientation (android phone) causes `screen.width` to change. For example on my Huawei android phone when in the portrait position `screen.width` == 360px while in landscape 640px. Taking into account that (at least as far as i know) `screen.width` holds `device-width` property value why the code below:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:360px){
  div {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:361px){
  div {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Doesn't work?

If `device-width` is linked with `screen.width` shouldn't it's value change accordingly with the actual device orientation just like `screen.width` does?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kusikelejo/edit?html,css,output  What didn't work? It seems working fine. try resize output frame.

Comment: I don't bother the desktop. As i written I'm testing the code on mobile android phone. And in such the above solution with `device-width` doesn't work - the background color doesn't change along with device orientation change.

Comment: i just checked the jsbin link on my phone with chrome app. It is changing somehow *-*

Answer (score 0):

> **device-width** refers to the width of the device itself, in other words,
>   the screen resolution of the device

Do you want something like this?

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
  div {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

/* Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {
  div {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm familiar with solution You shown. I just wanna know if the `screen.width` changes along with device orientation why `screen.width` don't?

Comment: device-width get static value from the device, and screen.width get the space who can be used.

Comment: you can check the documentation here https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/#device-width

Comment: So `screen.width` == `device-width` only initially (sth. like variable initialization) and when the device orientation changes so `screen.width` changes but `device-width` as static stays always the same?

Comment: Ok thx, but what do You mean "device-width only change the orientation"?

Comment: portrait or landscape to invert the values of width and height